# Embedding a browser in a 32bit Java/SWT/GTK application on 64bit linux

Tags: java, debian-squeeze, 32bit-64bit

I have created a Java Application that uses SWT 3.6 and now I want to use the browser widget on a 64bit Debian 6.0 system while using a 32bit Java JRE and the 32 bit SWT/GTK libraries.

I didn't feel this is a real programming question because I believe the server configuration part is the hard thing. If someone should guide me which libraries I have to install/configure to make this running it would be great.

I already installed 32bit GTK

```
apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk
```

and firefox

```
wget 'http://download.mozilla.org/?lang=de&product=firefox-18.0.1&os=linux'
mv index.html\?lang\=de\&product\=firefox-18.0.1\&os\=linux firefox-18.0.1.tar.bz2
tar xfvj firefox-18.0.1.tar.bz2
mv firefox /usr/local/
ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox
```

but still no luck.

Comment: Did the 32bit JVM not run or something? You would just need to have it installed in a separate location from the default java location, and then have the O/S user running the backend application have JAVA_HOME set to the correct 32bit JVM.

Comment: There is only 32bit Java installed, and the program works fully. Just the browser widget is not working, because it tries to embed firefox, and this doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Is the browser running on same system as the program? All localhost testing?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem seems to be here that I need 32bit GTK and althought I installed it like added to the question, it still doesn't work.